# how to fix build errors for Maven Mulesoft code

Tags: maven, build, mule, bamboo

I'm trying to build mulesoft code with maven in Bamboo.Build was successfull but now giving errors as below. I'm using Bamboo 6.5.0 and jdk 1.8. with Maven 3. The error details are as below and my pom.xml, settings.xml as well ! Any inputs appreciated !

```
    build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: NoFileAssignedException
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02        at org.apache.maven.plugins.install.InstallMojo.installProject(InstallMojo.java:152)
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02        at org.apache.maven.plugins.install.InstallMojo.execute(InstallMojo.java:108)
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02        ... 20 more
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02    Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.transfer.project.NoFileAssignedException: The packaging plugin for this project did not assign a main file to the project but it has attachments. Change packaging to 'pom'.
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02        at org.apache.maven.shared.transfer.project.install.internal.DefaultProjectInstaller.install(DefaultProjectInstaller.java:116)
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02        at org.apache.maven.plugins.install.InstallMojo.installProject(InstallMojo.java:140)
build   01-Oct-2018 11:46:02        ... 23 more
```

My pom.xml and settings.xml look as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mule</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycontacts-mule-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule mycontacts-mule-api Application</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.version>3.9.0</mule.version>

        <mule.munit.support.version>3.9.1</mule.munit.support.version>
        <munit.version>1.3.7</munit.version>

        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
        <application-name>mycontacts-mule-api</application-name>

        <proxy.api.version>1.0:15535407</proxy.api.version>
        <implementation.host>null</implementation.host>
        <implementation.port>80</implementation.port>
        <implementation.path>/api</implementation.path>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://prdbambap02:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://prdbambap02:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependencies for Mule CoE Begins -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/guru.nidi.raml/raml-tester-standalone -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-raml-el-gw</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId> mule-module-spring-config-gw</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-gw</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-gateway-client</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>gateway-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-dbserver-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-db</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-ws</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependencies for Mule CoE Ends -->
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

and my settings.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.mule.tools</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>mule-ee-repo</id>
            <username>balalba</username>
            <password>blbalbab</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors></mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mule-ee-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <mule-maven-plugin-version>2.2.1</mule-maven-plugin-version>
                <mule-username>username</mule-username>
                <mule-password>password</mule-password>
                <mule-client-id>blbalbalbal</mule-client-id>
                <mule-client-secret>blablblalbalba</mule-client-secret>
                <deployment-type>cloudhub</deployment-type>

                <business-group>group</business-group>


                <target-name>null</target-name>
                <target-type>null</target-type>
                <worker-size>Micro</worker-size>
                <worker-count>1</worker-count>
                <env-name>SIT</env-name>
            </properties>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>mule-ee-repo</id>
                    <name>mule-ee-repo</name>
                    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>mule-ee-profile</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: I'm not using install:install, I'm only using clean install, still seeing the error !

Comment: MuleSoft is aware of this and is actively working on this.

Comment: This isn't just Bamboo; it affects TeamCity as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Official support message:

https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Mule-Maven-Plugin-fails-during-deploy-with-error-Failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-plugins-maven-deploy-plugin-3-0-0-M1-deploy

Cause:

> A new version of the Maven Install Plugin has been published on the Maven public repositories (3.0.0-M1).
>   By default, Mule doesn't define a version for this plugin and picks the last one.

The page lists the following as a temporary solution, and suggests refreshing the above link for updates.

Update pom.xml to specify the Maven version to be used by the Mule Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</plugin>
```

---

**New** - the above is the original solution, which is now the alternative solution. The recommended solution is:

Update mule.tools.version in pom.xml:

```
<mule.tools.version>1.7</mule.tools.version>
```

And make sure this property is used by mule-app-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    ...
</plugin>
```

If you then get an error about unresolvable build extension, run the following from the project directory:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude="org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 4):

Apache Maven deployed a new version of the Maven Install Plugin to their repositories. It doesn't seem that it should have gone to the Public Repo, but still.

The solution is to fix the Maven plugin version in the Mule POM file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is the official recommendation while this is fixed.

Comment: Updating the mule-app-maven-plugin to version 1.7 should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is problem with incompatibility between new maven install plugin and mulesoft code. In my case it helped to use older install plugin - define in pluginManagement desired version of install maven plugin to use:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

We've just run into the same issue with our pipelines this morning, but to stop that NoFileAssignedException when the deploy phase happens, we had to explicitly exclude it within the POM for the Mule app;

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
  </plugin >
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
  </plugin>
```

Skipping the deploy of the app isn't a problem for us because the built artifact actually gets deployed by Git runner at the moment (in that particular environment).

Answer (score 2):

Please update the plugin to version 1.7, that should fix the problem.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, which happens because of new version of maven-install-plugin (3.0.0-M1).
Solution for my case is to skip installation of project with custom packaging (karaf-assembly) so adding following snippet in related pom.xml does it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
       <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Of course, built artifacts will not end in .m2 directory, but that is ok in my case.

Comment: I can't skip installation ! I need the artifacts in .m2 directory !

Comment: The maven-install-plugin version 3.0.0-M1 is not announced yet furthermore you should always define the versions of the plugins in your build.

Comment: how you mean not announced? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked after adding the following **explicit** in my project .pom file.

> ```
>            <plugin>
>                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
>                <version>2.5.2</version>
>            </plugin>
>            <plugin>
>                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
>                <version>2.8.2</version>
>            </plugin>
> ```

In my project artifiact maven-install-plugin 2.5.2 was already included, but not maven-deploy-plugin. It looks like it is using artifact maven-deploy-plugin under water. While it is not defined in the project .pom file, mvn picks up the last version in the repository (which is 3.0.0-M1) which ends with an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is picking 3.0.0-M1 version as it is installed in your m2 repository. you can restrict it by forced versioning. Open .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata-central-mirror.xml

Change as below to version 2.5.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <release>2.5.2</release>
    <versions>
      <version>maven-install-plugin</version>
      .....
      ......
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20180930132927</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```