# Getting failed to execute goals for maven in azure pipeline mule 4

Tags: maven, azure-devops, mule4

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project pipeline: Failed to deploy [D:\a\1\s\target\pipeline-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mule-application.jar] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have given the following commands to deploy to Mule Cloudhub
mvn deploy -DmuleDeploy and for package 
mvn package [image: Maven details for pipeline]
Also in my pom.xml file in Mule I have given the cloudHubDeployment details.I have tried running the azure pipeline multiple times but the mule app is not deployed to cloudhub.

Comment: [This kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583830/how-to-fix-build-errors-for-maven-mulesoft-code) seems to have something to do with the plugin version used by your project. And this is the issue about your project itself, what's the result if you run the command locally?

Comment: Hey I solved the error.Anyways thanks for your input!!!!

Comment: Glad to know it's resolved, you can consider [adding your solution as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to share the useful info! Just a reminder :)